# Enabling Chrome’s Translate Menu Command in a CefSharp Application

Tags: c#, translation, chromium, cefsharp

How to add the "Translate to English" item to the context menu of CEFSharp browser application?
[image: Google Chrome Context Menu]

Following tutorial from Our Code World ([How to add new items to the native Context Menu on a CefSharp control in WinForms](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/449/how-to-add-new-items-to-the-native-context-menu-on-a-cefsharp-control-in-winforms)) to customize the right click menu.  I can easily add menu items, but do not know how to invoke the required functionality.  Is there a method in one of the CEFSharp interface parameters I can call from the OnContextMenuCommand method to perform the translation or is this functionality something that needs to be completely custom developed?

If it is necessary to call a 3rd party translation service, how do I get access to all the text displayed in the browser and then replace it with the translation (getting and updating the correct DOM elements)?

Using CefSharp WinForms 71.0.0 obtained thru Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here in the next few days I'd suggest you ask on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php CefSharp is just a wrapper around the Chromium embedded framework.

Comment: For reference you can search the chromium source online using https://source.chromium.org/chromium?originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2F might be able to find some clues on how it's implemented.

Comment: @Jayden67 Have you solved your problem?
Share the solution, links...
thank you.